# How to add second table inside primary table below tr row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table, now I have to insert other table/div or stm in that table I have, so it should look like in the attached image.

[image: table]

I have made table already, and don't know how to insert gray color table below green row. I tried insert table inside td, but it don't work. Then I make a div's using display:table, it looks almost fine, but the prices cell align is bad. As you see in image all prices (300, 343, 300) must be same cell size.

I just need simple an example how I could do this as show in image. My table is width:100%;

Sry for no code, just need an example

Comment: Do post your code, please.

Comment: The first thing to post when posting a question on SO is the code you tried in order to solve your problem. We can help you fix code that isn't working but not write it for you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use for example code bellow for gray row:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td colspan="8"> your gray table </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes, that almost works, but currency cells were not the same size, so I add width propertie for both cells.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic example of placing a table inside another table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Table inside another table
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>C</td>
          <td>D</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```